# Design a table structure

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I am new to programming and very new to Data Base. My problem is that I need to create a table faculty

```
id(pk auto increment)  fact_name  department  subjects
```

Now my issue is that a faculty can have more then 2 or more departments or subjects, for me it is giving error saying duplicate primary key id.

What I want is

```
id(pk auto increment)  fact_name  department  subjects 
          1               ABC        1           1
          1               ABC        2           2
          1               ABC        3           3
```

Please suggest how to design my table where I can insert different data for same primary key or is there any other way.

Code

```
Create table faculty(
fact_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
fact_name varchar(20),
fact_email varchar(20) unique,
fact_password varchar(20),
year_id varchar(2),
sem_id varchar(2),
dept_id varchar(2),
subject_id varchar(2),
primary key ( fact_id,subject_id)
)
```

Comment: If you don't want to get down-voted you should further provide what you already tried, like the code that resulted in the 'duplicate primary key' issue, as like this the question is too vague and general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primary key is a unique identifying key, it can't be duplicated no matter what, if you want another duplicate key then add your own extra field

```
---------------------------------------------------
| pk | my key | fact_name | department | subjects |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    1   |    ABC    |     1      |     1    |
|  2 |    1   |    ABC    |     2      |     2    |
|  3 |    1   |    ABC    |     3      |     3    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

---

Ok according to what I understand now, you need a many to many relationship between subjects, departments and faculties, first split the faculty table

```
-------------------------------
| pk | fact_name | fact_email | 
-------------------------------
```

Then create a different table for example called `faculty_subjects`

```
---------------------------------------------
| pk | fact_id | department_id | subject_id |
---------------------------------------------
```

any extra details will be in the join table, not the faculty table.